# PHP imap_open(), OpenSSL, and no Cipher

Tags: email, ubuntu, ssl, tls1.2, dovecot

I have moved a PHP script to another server, and now fail to login to an IMAP (TLS) postbox:

```
TLS/SSL failure for mail.servername.de: SSL negotiation failed
```

It seems that the problem is caused by OpenSSL, because when I try to connect to the Mailserver from both servers, I get a connection in one case (the mailserver asking for input), but none in the other (the connection is closed, I am back to `bash`):

```
 openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.servername.de:993
```

The most obvious difference is here:

```
verify return:1
---

<snip>

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=mail.servername.de
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3398 bytes and written 483 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
```

And on th other server (where no connection is made)

```
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mail.servername.de
verify return:1
140410888582464:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2149:
---

<snip>

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = mail.servername.de

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3167 bytes and written 318 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Server public key is 2048 bit
```

On the mailserver `dovecot` is configured not to accept non-encrypted connections. But, I assume it already fails due to `dh key too small`, which seems to relate to cipher negotiation.

Now I simply fail to put the things together... Why does the SSL connection work from one server, but not from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: your new host has a newer version of OpenSSL probably with higher security settings which prohibit connecting to the host for reasons explained below.

"dh key too small" comes from OpenSSL and because of too low security.

Things changed, and for example in newest Debian versions and with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (and I guess it is similar for newer versions), the security was enhanced.

The best and simplest explanation I have found is on Debian wiki at https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1
which says:

> In Debian the defaults are set to more secure values by default. This
>   is done in the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf config file. At the end of the
>   file there is:
>
> ```
> [system_default_sect]
> MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
> CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
> ```
>
> This can results in errors such as:
>
> ```
> dh key too small
> ee key too small
> ca md too weak
> ```

Now the possible solutions in descending order of preference:

- ask the remote end to generate better "DH" values ("Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits"); the best explanations are at https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html; note specifically the "Administrators should use 2048-bit or stronger Diffie-Hellman groups with "safe" primes."
- configure your end specifically for this connnection to not use the OS default and lower your settings; it should be enough to set ciphers to "DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" in the code that does the connection
- (really, really, really not recommended) change the value of `SECLEVEL` from 2 to 1 in the global configuration file on your end. But this impacts all connections from your host not just this one so you are lowering the global security of your system just because of one low level of security from one remote node.

Answer (score 2):

As I own the "remote end" myself, I was able to increase security. The solution is simple, and may be relevant for others as well ...

The `dovecot` version is 2.2.x, which is of some relevance for the DH parmaters (see [Dovecot SSL configuration](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/)). In the configuration file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` you can simply add this line:

```
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
```

And eventually, it may be necessary to add this here to the main configuration file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` at the end:

```
!include conf.d/*.conf
```

Finally, it is important not to reload, but to restart dovecot.

```
systemctl restart dovecot
```

And suddently, the weight, troubles, and frustration of several hours is gone. Great...

Answer (score 2):

Further to the above, there's a change from dovecot 2.3.
ssl_dh_parameters_length is now not used, and ssl_dh must be used instead, to point to a file generated using

```
openssl dhparam 4096 > dh.pem
```

see https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/  and scroll down to SSL Security Settings.  That was the only change I had to make following the upgrade to get it to work properly again.  I put the dh.pem file in /etc/dovecot, so my line in 10-ssh.conf is

```
ssl_dh=</etc/dovecot/dh.pem
```